# How to access a variable that is chaning in a python script?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, raspberry-pi

I have a python script that is running a while loop for a countdown timer:

```
hour = 60
minute = 1

    while(hour + minute != 0):

            if minute == 0:
                    minute = 59
                    hour = hour - 1
            else:
                    minute = minute - 1

            time.sleep(1)
```

Now I have another script that I want to access the variables hour and minute at any given time. What's the best way to go about this?

Comment: Can you give an example - how to 2nd script will be executed? what is the relationship between those two scripts?

Comment: Both are going to be run with a bash script. I was under the assumption that since the first script has a while loop that has to run I can't really do anything else with that script correct? However I would like to be able to get what time is left on the countdown timer from the first script

Comment: Do you understand that the script in your question won't work as countdown timer? 1) time.sleep(1) - means 1 second - not 1 minute. 2) the time.sleep(1) ensure that at least 1 sec will pass ,but it might be much more than 1 sec

Answer (score 0):

Since you work on linux, the simplest solution may be writing minutes & seconds to a file and read from it, which avoids [asynchronous](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asynchrony_(computer_programming)) mechanism design.

```
# timer.py
with open("time.txt", "w+") as f:
    f.write(str(minutes) + ", " + str(seconds))

# script.py
with open("time.txt") as f:
    m, s = f.readline().split()
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is a good way to do your job with two process. But I think you may need inter progress communication.

please see the reference:
https://docs.python.org/2/library/ipc.html